# Average value of a complex valued function

Tags: integration

Given  that  $h(z)$ is  a  real-valued continuous  function  on  a  domain  $D$ and  $z_0$  be  a  point  in  $D$  and  the   disk  $\{|z-z_0|\lt \rho \}$  is  in  $D$ . The *average value*  of  $h(z)$ on the  **circle $\{|z-z_0|=r\}$  for $0\lt r\lt \rho$**  as  follows :
$$ A(r)=\int_0^{2\pi} h(z_0 + re^{i\theta }){{d\theta}\over {2\pi}} ,\ \ \ \ 0\lt r\lt \rho $$

Now $$|A(r)-h(z_0)|=\left|\int_0^{2\pi} [h(z_0 + re^{i\theta})-h(z_0)]{{d\theta}\over {2\pi}}\right|\\\le\int_0^{2\pi} \left|h(z_0 + re^{i\theta})-h(z_0)\right|{{d\theta}\over {2\pi}}$$

NOw  what  I  understand  from  this  is  that  , since  $h$  is  given  to be  continuous  on  $D$ so as  $r\rightarrow 0$ , $h(z_0+ re^{i\theta})\rightarrow h(z_0)$ and hence  the  integral  tends  to  $0$ and $A(r)$  tends  to  $h(z_0)$. .

But  this  is  written  in  the  book :

*The  continuity of  $h(z)$  at  $z_0$  guarantees  that  the  integrand  in  the  right hand  side  $\color{fuchsia}{tends\ \ to\ \ 0\ \ uniformly\ \ in\ \  \theta\ \ ,\ \ so\ \ that\ \ the\ \ integral\ \ tends\ \ to\ \ 0\ \ as\ \   r\rightarrow 0}$

I  have  a feeling  that  this  is  not  much  different  from  what  I  wrote  previously  except  the  part  "*tends  to  $0$  uniformly  in  $\theta$*" i.e.  the  $\color{fuchsia}{coloured}$  part .

Please  explain  that  part  clearly  to  me .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By continuity of $h$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|h(z)-h(z_0)|<\varepsilon$ for every $z$ with $|z-z_0|<\delta$.

I.e., if $r > 0$ is small enough,
$$
|h(z_0+re^{i\theta})-h(z_0)| < \varepsilon
$$
from which it follows that (again for $r > 0$ small enough)
$$
0 \le \int_0^{2\pi} |h(z_0+re^{i\theta})-h(z_0)| \,\frac{d\theta}{2\pi} \le \varepsilon.
$$
But this holds for every $\varepsilon > 0$, so the limit as $r \to 0$ must in fact be $0$.

To emphasize the point, you need an estimate of $|h(z_0+re^{i\theta})-h(z_0)|$ which is independent of $\theta$ to be able to bound the integral. Even if for every *fixed* $\theta$, $h(z_0+re^{i\theta}) \to h(z_0)$, this in itself isn't quite enough to guarantee that the integral tends to $0$ as $r \to 0$.

Comment: Could  you  please  explain  the  last  *three*  liners  of  your  answer  more  elaborately $?$  Why  is  this  not  quite  enough  to  guarantee  that  the  integral  will  tend  to  $0$  as  $r\rightarrow 0$  $?$

Comment: As an example (on $[0,1]$), let $f_n$ be a function whose graph is the polygonal line: $(0,0) \mapsto (\frac1n,n) \mapsto (\frac2n,0) \mapsto (1,0)$. Then $f_n(x) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ for every $x\in[0,1]$, but $\int f_n(x)\,dx = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: ok. I understand  that  part  but  what  does  "converge  uniformly  in  $\theta$  mean"  ?  I'm  sorry  if  annoying  you  repeating  the  question  but  thing  is  still  not  clear  to  me .

Comment: Uniformly in $\theta$ means just that: to have a bound independent of $\theta$. More precisely: $\sup_\theta |h(z_0+re^{i\theta})-h(z_0)| \to 0$ as $r \to 0$.